# newrelic override variables not working.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, newrelic

I'm trying to get deploys sent to New Relic.

according to this: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/ruby/recording-deployments-with-the-ruby-agent#Capistrano_Configuration

I should be able to set

```
set(:newrelic_revision) do
  tagname = repository =~ /\/([^\/]*)$/ && $1
  revnumber = source.query_revision(source.head()) { |cmd| `#{cmd}` }
  "#{tagname} (#{revnumber})"
end
```

and trying with

```
set(:newrelic_revision) do
  "v40 (a097fa)"
end
```

it still ignores in tries to look up the REVISION file. Is there some namespacing missing?

```
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update'
  * 2014-05-28 11:45:08 executing `newrelic:notice_deployment'
  * Getting log of changes for New Relic Deployment details
  * executing "cat /var/www/taxidepot/current/REVISION"
```

gems:

```
newrelic_rpm 3.6.8.164
capistrano 2.15.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I work for New Relic. The `cat` line is coming out of Capistrano itself when our recipe asks for the current revision.

It would be helpful to see more of your Capistrano deployment code to get a better idea of what might be happening.

Comment: my workaround was to use `curl -H "x-api-key: ... ` built manually in the script. yes, the `cat` comes out of capistrano itself because New relic recipe asks for it. New Relic shouldn't ask capistrano for the revision when I've told it what it is. `set(:newrelic_revision) "v40 (a097fa)"`. I'm not comfortable showing this deploy.rb of my client, but the newrelic_recipe and code changes was minimal and the problem has been pinpointed - the custom new_relic version is ignored.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me Mr Anonymous New Relic dude :) Appreciate it!